# Show progressbar while executing shell commands

Tags: java, android, shell, progressdialog

Im trying to make a progress bar appear during the time that I copy files (using shell commands). Here is my code:

```
    copyProgress = new ProgressDialog(Activ.this);
    copyProgress.setMessage("Copying");
    copyProgress.show();  

    Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cp /sdcard/file /system"});
    Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cp /sdcard/file2 /system"});
    .......

    copyProgress.dismiss();
```

I have multiple different processes that i need to execute, so how can i make a progress dialog appear at the start and get dismissed when the last file has successfully finished copying. I tried showing the dialog before procccess1 and dismiss after the last process, but that doesnt work. Thanks.

Apparently i need to wrap it in a Thread. Can someone show me how i would do this?

Comment: please show the code how you tried to implement this

Comment: Can you show how did you try the dialog to appear?

Comment: I added my progress dialog code. The problem is that it just doesnt appear at all.

Comment: It would likely be simpler (and definitely more portable, as the "cp" command is new to Android) to perform the copying in Java (in a background thread, or if expected to be lengthy, even a thread in a service).  There are many examples around of that.  Since such a copy will be done in blocks of moderate size, this also gives you a ready way to measure the progress within a file as well as across files.  You are then left only to figure out how to have the background copy operation periodically notify the UI of its progress.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If I do it the typical Java way, would it still work when I copy files onto /system? Ive done it using shell commands because I'm calling "su" before the command so that I get the priveleges to write to /system.

Comment: No, then you do have to use a helper process running as root.  So you may need to use process.waitFor() and/or periodically query the size of the target files.

Comment: As Chris said this is not going to work without root.  I added some stuff for checking the waitFor, but it still won;t work.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues are here in your original code. The code below handles the running of the processes on a background thread and checks their results using the waitFor call.  All of this is really moot anyway because you cannot copy to /system without root.

```
{   
   copyProgress = new ProgressDialog(Activ.this);
   copyProgress.setMessage("Copying");
   copyProgress.show();  
   new DoShellScriptyThingsAsyncThread().execute();
}

private class DoShellScriptyThingsAsyncThread extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        doCopy("file");
        publishProgress();
        doCopy("file2");
        publishProgress()
        return null;
    }

    private void  doCopy(String filename)
    {
        try    
    {            

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cp /sdcard/"  +filename +" /system"});
        InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();            
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
        //Now do some thing if this fails - which it will because you are trying
        // to copy something to system
      }
}
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... updateInteger)
    {
        //Update your progress dialog here!
        copyProgress.incrementProgress(5000);
    }
  }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        //Make your progress dialog go away here
        copyProgress.dismiss();
    }

};
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would wrap it in a thread?